# Interactive FAQ error

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make an interactive FAQ section where the answers are initially hidden but can be toggled on and off by clicking on the question. However, I'm getting a weird behavior wherein everything is fading out of the page. Please help me. The code is as follows:

(When you post your answer, please also tell me why my code doesn't work.)

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<h1>Frequently asked questions</h1>

<br/><br/>

<div id="qna">

<h3># Question</h3>
<p> This is the answer.</p>


</div>

</body>

<script>
$('document').ready(function(){
  $('#qna p').hide();
  $('#qna h3').toggle(
    function(){
      $(this).next('p').fadeIn();
    },
    function(){
      $(this).next('p').fadeOut();
    }
  ); //toggle
}); //ready
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [fadeToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/):

```
$('#qna h3').click(function() {
    $(this).next('p').fadeToggle();
})
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r56Q6/2/)**

Answer (score 3):

Here is the restructure of your code, and you can use `fadeToggle()` instead of alternate `fade-in` and `fade-out`

```
<script>
$('document').ready(function(){
  $('#qna p').hide();
  $('#qna h3').click(function(){
      $(this).next('p').fadeToggle();

  ); //toggle
}); //ready
</script>
```

Comment: Nice. Please look at the answer below by @Felix. More concise, IMHO. But I'm curious as to why my code didn't work...

Comment: lol, i was dosing and mess up my own code, ur code is not calling or handling an event so it will just fire right away and `fade-out` everything in the `h3 tag`

Answer (score 0):

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eu4bJ/)
**HTML**

```
<h1>Frequently asked questions</h1>
<div id="qna1" class="que">
<h3>Question 1</h3>
<p> This is the answer 1.</p>
</div>
<div id="qna2" class="que">
<h3>Question 2</h3>
<p> This is the answer 2.</p>
</div>
<div id="qna3" class="que">
<h3>Question 3</h3>
<p> This is the answer 3.</p>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('p').hide();
    $('.que h3').click(function(){
        $(this).next('p').toggle('slolw');
    });
});
```